How to get expected %ages with CIs for different possible responses from svy_vglm in svyVGAM?
I am looking to calculate survey-weighted percentages for categorical outcomes using the svy_vglm function of svyVGAM. For example, if the categorical variable could be A, B, or C, I simply want to estimate the weighted, population-level percentages (with CIs) of A, B, and C.
With simpler svy_glm it is possible to get these predicted values on the response scale for binomial models, but none of the usual functions seem to work to get these percentages and CIs for a categorical model. I feel like there must be some simple function or approach to doing this but I can't find anything that works.
A reprex to work with for the model would be the following, and the question is how to get the expected %ages of each category and their CIs from the svy_fit object:
library(tidyverse)
library(svyVGAM)

set.seed(123)

cat_data <-
  tibble(outcome = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
         weight = c(rep(2/3, 750), rep(2, 250)))

cat_svy_design <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = cat_data, weights = cat_data$weight)

cat_svy_fit <- svy_vglm(formula = outcome ~ 1,
                        family = multinomial(refLevel = "A"),
                        design = cat_svy_design)


You will have better chances of getting a useful answer if you supply a minimal reproducible example, including all libraries loaded and using a public dataset.

@Vincent I've included a minimal working example from which I would like to know how to calculate/generate the expected %ages and their CIs

Thanks for the example. Sorry to have you go through the trouble, but I tried a couple options I had in mind, and they didn't work. One issue is that there does not appear to be a predict() method at all in the svyGAM, so it's impossible for packages like marginaleffects to support it. Sorry!

That's ok, maybe useful for someone else. But yes exactly, the predict() type function doesn't seem to exist. I'm trying to find if there might be a way to just calculate them from the raw coefficients - I think it can work for the mean estimates but the key thing is really the CIs

You can get probabilities with predict like this
head(predict(cat_svy_fit$fit,type="response"))

ie, using the $fit component that's a vglm.  I don't think confidence intervals for predictions are provided yet.
